# React/Redux - Dispatch method - returning error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, axios

I'm currently trying to add and delete my items on the page and it's returning an error.

`Unhandled rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property data of undefined` pointing to `.catch` in both of in the below code.

```
export const addItem = (item) => (dispatch, 
getState) => {
 axios
  .post('/api/items', item, tokenConfig(getState))
  .then(res => dispatch({
    type: ADD_ITEM,
    payload: res.data
}))
  .catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
 );
};

export const deleteItem = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
axios
 .delete(`/api/items/${id}`, tokenConfig(getState))
 .then(res => dispatch({
    type: DELETE_ITEM,
    payload: id
}))
 .catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
 );
};
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

The returnErrors method referenced above is from another file that is here:

```
import { GET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS } from './types';

// RETURN ERRORS

export const returnErrors = (msg, status, id = null) => {
 return {
   type: GET_ERRORS,
payload: { msg, status, id }
 };
};


// CLEAR ERRORS

export const clearErrors = () => {
 return {
   type: CLEAR_ERRORS
 };
};
```

I have put a `console.log(err.response)` and a `console.log(err.response.data)` right above the `dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.data));` and returned `undefined` for the first and `uncaught (in promise) cannot read property of undefined`

I was told by someone that

`This essentially means your error object doesn't have correct data. Please look into the error object returned. It could be an issue with items/user api, it should return correct error object.`

*items api route*

```
router.post('/', auth, (req, res) => {
 const newItem = new Item({
   name: req.body.name
 })

   newItem.save().then(item => res.json(item));
});

// DELETE api/items/:id
// Delete an item
// Private

router.delete('/:id', auth, (req, res) => {
  Item.findById(req.params.id)
   .then(item => item.remove().then(() => res.json({ deleted: true 
})))
   .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ deleted: false }));
})
```

Not sure where data is undefined. Anyone see anything missing?

You can take a look at what the chrome dev tools network tab returned here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXuAR.jpg

*authActions*

```
// Check token & Load User
// Want to check routes/auth.js for user by id that's included with token
// Going to use asynchronous request, use dispatch
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {

// User loading
 dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });


// Fetch user
 axios.get('/api/auth/user', tokenConfig(getState))
  .then(res => dispatch({
     type: USER_LOADED,
  payload: res.data
 }))
  .catch(err => {
    dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
  dispatch({
     type: AUTH_ERROR
   });
  });
 };

// Register User

export const register = ({ name, email, password }) => dispatch => {
// Headers
 const config = {
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

// Request body

const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

axios.post('/api/users', body, config)
 .then(res => dispatch({
     type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  payload: res.data
 }))
 .catch(err => {
  dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'REGISTER_FAIL'));
  dispatch({
  type: REGISTER_FAIL
  });
 });
};

// LogIn

export const login = ({ email, password }) => dispatch => {
// Headers
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
 }

 // Request body

 const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

 axios.post('/api/auth', body, config)
  .then(res => dispatch({
     type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  payload: res.data
 }))
  .catch(err => {
  dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 
 'LOGIN_FAIL'));
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_FAIL
  });
 });
};


// LogOut

export const logout = () => {
  return {
   type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS
 };
};


// Setup config/headers and Token

export const tokenConfig = (getState) => {

// Get token from localstorage
const token = getState().auth.token;

// Headers
const config = {
   headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
 }

 // Check if token exists, add to Headers
  if(token) {
    config.headers['x-auth=token'] = token;
  }

  return config;
 }
```

Comment: appreciate that

Comment: Show the exact server response (Chrome DevTools -> Network -> etc)

Comment: i've done that, is there anyway i can share a screenshot

Comment: https://imgur.com/D5OGLpf

Comment: The thing is I don't see any request to `/api/items` in your screenshot. There are 3 common requests in Network (js + map + svg) and no xhr. From the other hand, console shows 401 for some `/api/items`. If you make sure that  `/api/items` is being sent, you should be able to open it in Network tab.

Comment: Also, I would suggest you to investigate what is `err` in your catcher (we already got that `err` does not have `response` property).

Comment: when i console log it, it says that `err is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

Base your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXuAR.jpg, your request to `axios.delete('/api/items/${id}` do not reach the route `/api/items/:id`.

Why I said so?

The response status is 401 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXuAR.jpg), meaning that **Unauthorized**. The endpoint of the route `router.delete('/:id'` might be protected by the authentication middleware or something like that.

To solve it,

**First**

You need to make an authenticated request using the way you set up for your api either basic authentication, oauth[2], or your customized one.

**Then**

Before dispatch `dispatch(returnErrors...`, you need to check if the data exists.

```
axios
 .delete(`/api/items/${id}`, tokenConfig(getState))
 .then(res => dispatch({
    type: DELETE_ITEM,
    payload: id
 }))
 .catch(err => {
   if(error.status === 404) {
      // here, you are sure that error.response.data exists
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)   
   }
   else {
      // do something else to handle the error
   }

 })
```

**Remember that ** the caught error can be anything ranging from your error status 400, 500,... to you un-caught error within the `.then(...)`.

Comment: hm ok, this is my first time using react/redux and the set up took awhile, please take a look at the code that was added

Comment: @mph85 The error is not related to redux itself. Fully getting the idea of my answer at **First** section above will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The inner promise to remove the item remains in a pending state and as you have noted doesn't return any response.

To have an idea what is happening.

```
Item.findById(req.params.id)
   .then(item => item.remove().then(() => res.json({ deleted: true 
})))
   .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ deleted: false }));
})
```

can be simplified to

```
P.then(p => Q)
```

where `P` and `Q` are promises objects.

When `P` is fulfilled, it returns `Q` and `Q` continues to remain in a pending state waiting for it to be resolved.

You can resolve `Q` by flattening the `then` chain to handle when the remove operation is fulfilled.

```
Item.findById(req.params.id)
   .then(item => item.remove())
   .then(() => res.json({ deleted: true }))
   .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ deleted: false }));
```

Comment: appreciate the response. I just revised it and it's still giving me that same error

Comment: that's curious. Are you by chance using the mongoose library? Also, the server needs to be restarted when you revise it.

Comment: I am using mongoose, but also have nodemon installed so it automatically restarts the server on any changes

Comment: How about using the [`Model.findByIdAndRemove`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) method available in mongoose?

Comment: Can you confirm that the request handler is executed? The request may not be process past the `auth` middleware

Comment: ive added my authActions file, if you can see what' sgoin gon